# How to change the color of the line's number where a mark is set in VIM editor?

Tags: vim, plugins, editor, text-editor, vi

As the question states , I would like to change the color of the number of lines where I set a mark, is there a simple way to do it ? the editor I'm using is Vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done.

Alternatively, you could try to set a sign on the marked line: `:help sign-support`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a experience VimL developer, here are some pointers:

Define the desired color something like this:

```
    hi AndreasColor term=reverse cterm=bold ctermfg=White ctermbg=Red guifg=White guibg=Red
```

on regular intervals (see :help timer_start) get all marks like this:

```
let m = execute("marks")
```

loop over marks and highlight the lines you want with this:

```
call matchaddpos("AndreasColor", [<line number>]
```